# Mobile OS, languages for their APPs and HTML 5

Tags: android, ios, windows, html, mobile

There are the 3 popular mobile OS:

1. Android
2. iOS
3. Windows Phone

   - Which programming language (s) is used for their apps, for each of the 3?
   - Is HTML 5 a replacement for any of the languages? if not, what's the hype with HTML 5 and mobile apps?
   - Java is cross platform (I believe because of JVM), can java be used to write apps for all the 3?

Answer (score 0):

For Android the programming langauge used is Java. Eclipse/Android Studio  is the IDE used widely for it.
For IOS the programming language used is Objective C and Swift. Xcode is the IDE used for coding. 
For Windows Phone the language used is C# and Visual Studio is the IDE. 
Now to create an App in this 3 platform you would have to code separately for each. This is where creating Hybrid Apps can save time and money. 
Using Phonegap ( http://phonegap.com/) you can code using HTML5 , CSS and Javascript and then you can deploy it to each of this platforms. Having said this the performance of hybrid apps is less compared to Native Apps but still for a good number of applications you can go for Hybrid Apps instead of native apps.